# background-image does not display in my react application

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to make a simple component and set its background image using separate css file.

My App.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header-img">
        {/* <img src={require('./header.jpg')} alt='header-img'/> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The CSS file:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 426px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('./header.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /* background-color: aquamarine; */
}
```

***Here is CodeSandBox link*** https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-silence-cvhyt?file=/src/styles.css:0-309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using files through pure CSS will work only on static files, so you need to put your images in the `public` folder.

That's because React applications that bootstrapped with `create-react-app` are using `webpack` for bundling the `src` folder, accessing a path like `'./header.jpg'` through CSS won't bundle the file.

```
// public/header1.jpg

.header-img {
  background-image: url("./header1.jpg");
}
```

[image: Edit sweet-shaw-m6pwo]

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend ❤️